# Query objects by date range - Error - {TypeError}expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, django, orm

I am trying to get all the data from tasklist table where due_data should be in between today's date and date passed via URL.

Filter Query objects by date range in Django showing error - {TypeError}expected string or bytes-like object

```
Models.py

class TaskList(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   tasks = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   due_date = models.DateField(null=False)  # e.g. 2019-01-15 

   task_state = models.ForeignKey(States, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
      db_table = 'tasklist'


Views.py
today = date.today().isoformat() 

#task_due_date - say '2019-05-13' passing as a string via url 
task_obj = TaskList.objects.filter(due_date=[today, task_due_date]) # error in this line
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to filter a `QuerySet` for a date *range*, you should use the [**`__range`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range):

```
task_obj = TaskList.objects.filter(due_date__range=(today, task_due_date))
```

If you write `due_date=...` it simply expects a string or `date` object, or something similar to perform an equality check: it will then only return `TaskList`s that are due on that specific date.